# Replace values in matrix with different size in R

Tags: r

I want to replace values in the first column of mat1

```
mat1 <- matrix(c("vect-1822", "vect3", "vect-1818", "vect3", "vect-2030", "vect4", "vect-1926", "vect5", "vect-1818", "vect9", "vect-1818", "vect3", "vect-2030", "vect7"), ncol = 2, byrow=T)
```

with values from the second column in mat2:

```
mat2 <- matrix(c("vect-1822", "1", "vect-1818", "33", "vect-2030", "34", "vect-1926", "42"), ncol = 2, byrow=T)
```

The result will be :

```
mat_res <- matrix(c("1", "vect3", "33", "vect3", "34", "vect4", "42", "vect5", "33", "vect9", "33", "vect3", "34", "vect7"), ncol = 2, byrow=T)
```

I tried with two index i and j, but it is not optimal because my matrix is very large

Answer (score 0):

We can use named vector to match and replace

```
mat3 <- mat1
mat3[,1] <- setNames(mat2[,2], mat2[,1])[mat1[,1]]
```

-checking with OP's output

```
identical(mat3, mat_res)
#[1] TRUE
```